# Prove that $\int_{0}^{1} f^{2}(x) \mathrm{d} x=(n+1)^{2}\left(\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \mathrm{d} x\right)^{2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, definite-integrals

> Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ that satisfies
>
> $$\int_{0}^{1} x^{k} f(x) \,\mathrm{d} x = 0$$
>
> for all $k \in \{1,2, \dots, n\}$. Prove that
>
> $$\int_{0}^{1} f^{2}(x) \,\mathrm{d} x = (n+1)^{2} \left( \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \,\mathrm{d} x \right)^{2}$$

---

I fail to  solve it
\begin{aligned}
&\text {Suppose } f(x)=a_{n} x^{n}+\ldots+a_{0}.\\\\
&\int_{0}^{1} f^{2}(x)\,\mathrm{d} x=\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_{i} \int_{0}^{1} x^{i} f(x)\,\mathrm{d} x=a_{0} \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \,\mathrm{d} x.\\\\
&\text {So we only need to prove}\\
&\frac{a_{0}}{(n+1)^{2}}=\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \,\mathrm{d} x.\\\\
&\text{But I can't prove it. So how to prove it?}
\end{aligned}